# Verify if the user already exists Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I already have a code to check if the user email is already registered, but now I need check another values in MySQL.

In my code have an Input with name 'cpfcnpj'  and need to consult it in 2 columns (cpf and cnpj), but it's nothing returning the error, as happen with email.

My code

**Controller**

```
if($this->input->post("cpfcnpj")){
    $this->session->set_userdata(array("cpfcnpj" => $this->input->post("cpfcnpj")));
    $ret = $this->cliente_model->verificaCpfcnpj($this->session->userdata("cpfcnpj"));
    if($ret){
        $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'This CPF/CNPJ already exist!</a> :)');
        redirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
        die();
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
public function verificaCpfcnpj($cpfcnpj){
    $this->db->select("cpf,cnpj");
    $this->db->where('cpf',$cpfcnpj);
    $this->db->where('cnpj',$cpfcnpj);
    $this->db->where('status',0);

    if($this->session->userdata('usu_id')){
        $this->db->where('id <> '.$this->session->userdata('usu_id'));
    }
    $query = $this->db->get('ga845_clientes');
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0){
        $row = $query->row(); 

        return $row->cpf;
        return $row->cnpj;
    }else{
        return "";
    }
}
```

**View**

```
    <form action="cliente/novoCadastro" method="post" class="clearfix form form-cadastro">
        <input type="hidden" name="tipo" id="tipoPessoa"  value="f">
        <div class="campo">
            <label class="lbl" for="">CPF/CNPJ</label>
            <input type="text" class="input-text text cpfcnpj required" name="cpfcnpj" id="cpfcnpj">
        </div>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Continuar" class="btn">
    </form>
```

Comment: FYI, You are never going to get the second return's data from `return $row->cpf;
        return $row->cnpj;` because the first `return` halts the execution of the method.

Comment: Have you dumped the sql string that codeigniter creates to check that it is creating what you expect? What happens when you run the rendered query direcyly on your database? We cannot help you at this point.  There could be a logical error or typo, but we can't be sure.   Your question needs more clarity/details.